# add class when click in choice word

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have class "selected" it has background color red I want when click in word in the sidebar give the class "selected" to the same company have this name on the right-hand side and at the same time another company  that not select be hidden

code: https://codepen.io/El7raq/pen/VwWjjgK

I, mean something like this in the dashboard we select name some me this section only -> https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DzLg26BWmMpMhlQ-lS08UK4r74GTiDut?usp=sharing

***HTML***

```
  <section class="business-partners">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h2 class="col-12 business-partners-header">Business Partners</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Start slider -->

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="slide">
                        <h4 class="slid-header">| Partners</h4>
                        <p id="zoom" class="partners partner-selected"><span>Zoom</span></p>
                        <p id="jabra" class="partners"><span>Jabra</span></p>
                        <p id="epos" class="partners"><span>EPOS</span></p>
                        <p id="dten" class="partners"><span>DTEN</span></p>
                        <p id="ttec" class="partners"><span>TTec</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- End slider -->
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-12">

                    <div id="zoom" class="partners-content selected">
                        <h2 class="partners-name"><a href="https://zoom.us/">Zoom</a></h2>
                        <img class="partners-img" src="../images/business-partners/zoom.jpg" alt="zoom" srcset="">
                        <p class="partners-description">
                            Zoom Video Communications, Inc. brings teams together to get more done in a frictionless video environment. easy, reliable, and innovative video-first unified communications platform provides video meetings, voice, webinars, and chat across desktops, phones, mobile devices, and conference room systems. Zoom helps enterprises create elevated experiences with leading business app integrations and developer tools to create customized workflows.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Zoom’s value is to care. We care for our customers, employees, company, community, and selves. Our culture of delivering happiness stems from this value.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="jabra" class="partners-content">
                        <h2 class="partners-name"><a href="https://www.mea.jabra.com/about/">Jabra</a></h2>
                        <img class="partners-img" src="../images/business-partners/jabra_logo.jpg" alt="zoom" srcset="">
                        <p class="partners-description">
                            a global brand with a serious passion for sound. Thanks to our expertise in consumer, professional and medical audio technology, our passion is backed up by unrivaled knowledge of the human ear. We’re in the business of helping you hear what you want to hear – from letting the right sound in, to filtering disruptive noise out – but our products are about so much more than that, packed with intuitive features to make life sound better.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="epos" class="partners-content">
                        <h2 class="partners-name"><a href="https://www.eposaudio.com/">EPOS</a></h2>
                        <img class="partners-img" src="../images/business-partners/EPOS_Logo_-_Black_-_Large.jpg" alt="zoom" srcset="">
                        <p class="partners-description">
                            EPOS delivers high-end audio solutions designed for enterprise and gaming. Based on pioneering audio technology, EPOS strives to unleash human potential by perfecting audio experiences and delivering innovative design and performance with all of our audio solutions.                        <p>
                            Zoom’s value is to care. We care for our customers, employees, company, community, and selves. Our culture of delivering happiness stems from this value.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            EPOS headquarters is located in Copenhagen, Denmark, and is a key hub for our business. EPOS builds on more than 115 years of experience in audio innovation. We operate in a global market with offices and partners in more than 60 countries.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            EPOS Name is derived from Latin and ancient Greek and is used to describe epic stories, speech, and poetry. The name encapsulates our dedication to creating solutions that enable ways of communication through the Power of Audio.                        </p>
                        <p>
                            EPOS is part of the Demant group – a world-leading audio and hearing technology group that offers solutions and services to help people connect and communicate with the world around them. The Demant Group operates in a global market with companies in more than 30 countries, employs more than 16,000 employees, and generates annual revenue of DKK 14.5 billion.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="dten" class="partners-content">
                        <h2 class="partners-name"><a href="https://eu.dten.com/gb">DTEN</a></h2>
                        <img class="partners-img" src="../images/business-partners/DIC_i_Yi_400x400.jpg" alt="zoom" srcset="">
                        <p class="partners-description">
                            DTEN builds innovative communications technology creating the ideal environment to communicate and collaborate.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            DTN develops award-winning collaboration solutions that combine all-in-one cutting- edge features, plug-and-play ease, high quality performance and affordability.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            DTEN's Zoom certified appliances and integrated service subscriptions revolutionize the way teams around the world connect, communicate and collaborate.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Founded in 2015, DTEN is rapidly becoming a recognized international leader for innovation and accessibility in communication.
                        </p>
                        <h4>
                            DTEN D7
                            Wins 2019 Red Dot Best Of The Best Award
                        </h4>
                        <p>
                            DTEN is a 2019 recipient of the prestigious Red Dot: Best of the Best Award for D7. The Red Dot Award recognizes D7 for innovative product design, including breakthrough technology, inherent functionality and streamlined aesthetics.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="ttec" class="partners-content">
                        <h2 class="partners-name"><a href="https://www.hellottec.com/">TTec</a></h2>
                        <img class="partners-img" src="../images/business-partners/ttec.jpg" alt="zoom" srcset="">
                        <p class="partners-description">
                            Zoom Video Communications, Inc. brings teams together to get more done in a frictionless video environment. easy, reliable, and innovative video-first unified communications platform provides video meetings, voice, webinars, and chat across desktops, phones, mobile devices, and conference room systems. Zoom helps enterprises create elevated experiences with leading business app integrations and developer tools to create customized workflows.                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Zoom’s value is to care. We care for our customers, employees, company, community, and
                            selves. Our culture of delivering happiness stems from this value.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

***CSS***

```
.business-partners-body{
    position: relative;
}
.business-partners-body .top-svg{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    top: 40px;
}
.business-partners {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.business-partners .business-partners-header {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 45px;
}
.business-partners .business-partners-header:after {
    background-color: #000;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 4px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 40px;
}
.business-partners .business-partners-header:after {
    left: 0.5em;
    margin-right: -50%;
}
/*Partners slider*/
.slide {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    min-height: 445px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.slide .slid-header {
    padding: 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
.slide .partners {
    padding: 15px 10px 10px 15px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.slide .partner-selected {
    color: var(--primary-color);
}
.slide .partners span:hover {
    color: var(--hover-color)
}
/* Partners content*/
.partners-content {
    margin-left: 80px;
    /* display: none; */
}
.partners-content .partners-name {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.partners-content .partners-img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.selected {
    display:block;
    background-color: red;
}
```

thank's for the help

Comment: Can you please simplify "what is actually wrong"? Your problem statement is hard to understand

Comment: now I have a sidebar that has names like 'zoom', 'Jabara' and on another side have some DIVs each div have content, for example, I want to select zoom from the sidebar when clicking on zoom just show zoom and another DIVs be hidden 

note: *I let another divs appear to make developers how to want help see there are more div but it must be hidden untile selected it from sidebar

Comment: some thing like this bro: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DzLg26BWmMpMhlQ-lS08UK4r74GTiDut?usp=sharing

Comment: What JavaScript have you tried?

Comment: the dashboard is just a template, I do not know how can I do like this in video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with below code :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.partners').click(function(){
    $('.partners').removeClass('partner-selected');
    $('.partners-content').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('partner-selected');
    var side_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('partners-content').hide();
    if($('div#' + side_id).hasClass('partners-content')){
        $("div#" + side_id).addClass("selected");
        $("div#" + side_id).show();
   }
  });
});
```

```css
.business-partners-body{
    position: relative;
}
.business-partners-body .top-svg{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    top: 40px;
}
.business-partners {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.business-partners .business-partners-header {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 45px;
}
.business-partners .business-partners-header:after {
    background-color: #000;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 4px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 40px;
}
.business-partners .business-partners-header:after {
    left: 0.5em;
    margin-right: -50%;
}
/*Partners slider*/
.slide {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    min-height: 445px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.slide .slid-header {
    padding: 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
.slide .partners {
    padding: 15px 10px 10px 15px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.slide .partner-selected {
    color: var(--primary-color);
}
.slide .partners span:hover {
    color: var(--hover-color)
}
/* Partners content*/
.partners-content {
    margin-left: 80px;
    /* display: none; */
}
.partners-content .partners-name {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.partners-content .partners-img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.partners-content{
  display:none;
}
.selected {
    display:block;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="business-partners">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h2 class="col-12 business-partners-header">Business Partners</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Start slider -->

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="slide">
                        <h4 class="slid-header">| Partners</h4>
                        <p id="zoom" class="partners partner-selected"><span>Zoom</span></p>
                        <p id="jabra" class="partners"><span>Jabra</span></p>
                        <p id="epos" class="partners"><span>EPOS</span></p>
                        <p id="dten" class="partners"><span>DTEN</span></p>
                        <p id="ttec" class="partners"><span>TTec</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- End slider -->
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-12">

                    <div id="zoom" class="partners-content selected">
                        <h2 class="partners-name"><a href="https://zoom.us/">Zoom</a></h2>
                        <img class="partners-img" src="../images/business-partners/zoom.jpg" alt="zoom" srcset="">
                        <p class="partners-description">
                            Zoom Video Communications, Inc. brings teams together to get more done in a frictionless video environment. easy, reliable, and innovative video-first unified communications platform provides video meetings, voice, webinars, and chat across desktops, phones, mobile devices, and conference room systems. Zoom helps enterprises create elevated experiences with leading business app integrations and developer tools to create customized workflows.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Zoom’s value is to care. We care for our customers, employees, company, community, and
                            selves. Our culture of delivering happiness stems from this value.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="jabra" class="partners-content">
                        <h2 class="partners-name"><a href="https://www.mea.jabra.com/about/">Jabra</a></h2>
                        <img class="partners-img" src="../images/business-partners/jabra_logo.jpg" alt="zoom" srcset="">
                        <p class="partners-description">
                            a global brand with a serious passion for sound. Thanks to our expertise in consumer, professional and medical audio technology, our passion is backed up by unrivaled knowledge of the human ear. We’re in the business of helping you hear what you want to hear – from letting the right sound in, to filtering disruptive noise out – but our products are about so much more than that, packed with intuitive features to make life sound better.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="epos" class="partners-content">
                        <h2 class="partners-name"><a href="https://www.eposaudio.com/">EPOS</a></h2>
                        <img class="partners-img" src="../images/business-partners/EPOS_Logo_-_Black_-_Large.jpg" alt="zoom" srcset="">
                        <p class="partners-description">
                            EPOS delivers high-end audio solutions designed for enterprise and gaming. Based on pioneering audio technology, EPOS strive to unleash human potential by perfecting audio experiences and delivering innovative design and performance with all of our audio solutions.                        <p>
                            Zoom’s value is to care. We care for our customers, employees, company, community, and
                            selves. Our culture of delivering happiness stems from this value.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            EPOS headquarters is located in Copenhagen, Denmark, and is a key hub for our business. EPOS builds on more than 115 years of experience in audio innovation. We operate in a global market with offices and partners in more than 60 countries.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            EPOS Name is derived from Latin and ancient Greek and is used to describe epic stories, speech and poetry. The name encapsulates our dedication to create solutions that enable ways of communication through the Power of Audio.                        </p>
                        <p>
                            EPOS is part of the Demant group – a world-leading audio and hearing technology group that offers solutions and services to help people connect and communicate with the world around them. The Demant Group operates in a global market with companies in more
                            than 30 countries, employs more than 16,000 employees and generates an annual revenue of DKK 14.5 billion.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="dten" class="partners-content">
                        <h2 class="partners-name"><a href="https://eu.dten.com/gb">DTEN</a></h2>
                        <img class="partners-img" src="../images/business-partners/DIC_i_Yi_400x400.jpg" alt="zoom" srcset="">
                        <p class="partners-description">
                            DTEN builds innovative communications technology creating the ideal environment to communicate and collaborate.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            DTEN develops award-winning collaboration solutions that combine all-in-one cutting- edge features, plug-and-play ease, high quality performance and affordability.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            DTEN's Zoom certified appliances and integrated service subscriptions revolutionize the way teams around the world connect, communicate and collaborate.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Founded in 2015, DTEN is rapidly becoming a recognized international leader for innovation and accessibility in communication.
                        </p>
                        <h4>
                            DTEN D7
                            Wins 2019 Red Dot Best Of The Best Award
                        </h4>
                        <p>
                            DTEN is a 2019 recipient of the prestigious Red Dot: Best of the Best Award for D7. The Red Dot Award recognizes D7 for innovative product design, including breakthrough technology, inherent functionality and streamlined aesthetics.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="ttec" class="partners-content">
                        <h2 class="partners-name"><a href="https://www.hellottec.com/">TTec</a></h2>
                        <img class="partners-img" src="../images/business-partners/ttec.jpg" alt="zoom" srcset="">
                        <p class="partners-description">
                            Zoom Video Communications, Inc. brings teams together to get more done in a frictionless video environment. easy, reliable, and innovative video-first unified communications platform provides video meetings, voice, webinars, and chat across desktops, phones, mobile devices, and conference room systems. Zoom helps enterprises create elevated experiences with leading business app integrations and developer tools to create customized workflows.                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Zoom’s value is to care. We care for our customers, employees, company, community, and
                            selves. Our culture of delivering happiness stems from this value.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```